# After deploying to Azure Web apps, some modules are not automatically installed

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment, npm, package.json

After deploying to Azure Web apps, some modules are not automatically installed.

After deploying, the following error is output.

```
Error: Can not find module 'Cookie-parser'
```

At that time, I run 'npm install cookie-parser --save'.

In the package.json, the dependencies of the cookie-parser is surely saved.

```
{
  "name": "solo",
  "description": "demo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "lostsupervisor",
  "engines": {
     "node": ">=6.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
     "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
     "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
     "ejs": "^2.5.6",
     "express": "^4.15.4",
     "express-session": "^1.15.4",
     "mssql": "^4.0.4",
     "tedious": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
     "start": "node index.js"
  } 
}
```

However, the same event occur after deploying next time.

Could you teach me a solution?

Comment: How did you deploy the application? From FTP, local Git etc.?

Comment: @Aaron Chen Thankyou for responding.From bitbucket.I'm using azure deployment option.

Comment: Are you able to install `cookie-parser` running the command `npm install` with this `package.json` on your local? I believe "*Dependencies*" should be "*dependencies*".

Comment: @Aaron Chen Sorry.My post is incorrect.I corrected my post.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue on my side with the package.json. Can you please check that whether the `cookie-parser` folder exists in the node_module by using **App Service Editor** which can be accessed via `https://<yourappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/`?

Comment: @AaronChen Thank you I checked it. after npm install,there are package.https://gyazo.com/99de8288902eda790601a35efbd83230?token=8bb9f4a493b37d9138db57da37f95976

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by package-lock.json being not being pushed.
I solved it by pushing it.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Cookie-parser` which is wrong.

In NPM modules while downloading npm **upper** and **lower** cases matter. Change it to `cookie-parser`, upper `C` is causing the problem.

Comment: sorry it's miss typing.the correct description is 'cookie-parser'

Comment: @YoshihideNishimoto yes my friend

Comment: @YoshihideNishimoto please set it as answered if you can : )

Comment: Sorry,It has not been resolved yet.

Only The description of this post is incorrect, and the description of package.json is 'cookie-parser' correct.

Comment: if you still do `npm install` while `.json` file has `Cookie-parser`, it will return the same error as it will try to install all the modules from `.json` file

Comment: json file's description is "cookie-parser",this post's description is miss.I mean.Sorry